# How can I use node module in react app after production build?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, electron

I have a project which is created in Electron.js. It uses simple HTML files. But now I want to convert this app into a React app.
While using HTML files directly, I am able to use node modules like `electron`, requiring main `app.js` file and all.
After building the project with webpack, the React app will get converted into static files. So how can I access the node modules after the build?

Comment: do you have file name called package.json in your project?

Comment: When webpack builds your project, it includes the referred dependencies which makes it a "bundler"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Electron-React boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) for your project. As this contains all the basic configurations for building electron-react project. Go through the [electron-react docs](https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/docs/installation) and setup an initial electron-react app.

> ```
> # First, clone the repo via git:
> git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate.git your-project-name
> cd your-project-name
> # And then install dependencies with yarn:
> yarn
> ```

All the modules listed on `dependencies` on `package.json` will be bundled in the production stage. So the relevant modules can be accessed on the build stage too. You can create components with your html files.

Make sure enable `nodeIntegration` on your `BrowserWindow`, so the nodemodules can be accessed by the renderer process.

```
webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the electron-jsx package to work (I'm the author of the package), is simple and easy

Only you need that in you index.html file:

```
<script>
require("electron-jsx")(__dirname, {
    reactDir: "./react-sources",
})
</script>
<script react-src="./react-sources/index.jsx">
```

And you can work with react normal (without webpack), and, additional, you can call any node package with ES6 import for react

More info and docs for the package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-jsx

https://github.com/mdjfs/electron-jsx

PD: You also need set nodeIntegration to true